# Would preserving your Eyes from Light keep them healhty?

Tags: human-anatomy, vision, eyes

I [read about](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-eyesight-deterio/) why eyesight diminishes *with age*.
I am aware of the fact that there are different causes that can affect the quality of image received by our eyes and that being vague would not lead to a clear answer, but I will try to make it as clear as possible.

I am wondering if worsening of the ciliary muscle is affected by how much light the eye receives or at least how much **we use it**.

There might be other areas affected by high light intake. Because the title of the question might not be clear enough: I basically mean the following:

*Is our eyesight determined to worsen **with age** or does it **depend on** how the eyes are "used"?*